# Processing and rendering data from mixture of static data + Room Sqlite data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

I have an Android App which uses a two-dimensional data set, eg:

```
  1 2 3
1 A B C
2 D E F
3 G H I
```

The A,B,C values of this data can come from one of two places:

1. A hard coded Map in a Kotlin class (the defaults).
2. Optional override values in a Room sqlite DB.

A user can optionally customise certain values, for example some database entries of overrides might look like this:

```
x,y,value
2,2,X
3,1,Y
3,3,Z
```

Which would update my merged data to this:

```
  1 2 3
1 A B Y
2 D X F
3 G H Z
```

I have the override data being added to the DB, and I have the source data in a Kotlin class, but I am struggling with the correct approach to retrieve and merge this data for use in computations and also for rendering as a table for the user.

How can I approach this? I'm aware of LiveData and RecyclerView but the examples I've followed assume a full dataset in the DB, so I don't know how I would 'fill in the gaps' using the data in my Kotlin class. Additionally I am not sure I should use LiveData for the computation aspects which involve comparing some arbitrary input the user has made to a value in the table.

Any advice welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

As is standard in these scenarios, shortly after posting the question I came up with an answer. It seems logical so I'll go with it for now, here's the gist of it.

I created a ViewModel containing a LiveData list of my data. I then added an observer inside onCreate of the relevant Activities.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    myViewModel.myData.observe(this, Observer {
        data -> data?.let { myStaticDataClass.mergeFromDatabase(it) }
    })
}
```

Then the `mergeFromDatabase` method would merge the records from the database into my static data, thus creating the merged version.

```
fun mergeFromDatabase(dbValues: List<MyData>)
{
    for (value in dbValues) {
        staticData[value.keyY]?.set(value.keyX, value.customValue)
    }
}
```

Whether it's the perfect solution I don't know, but so far so good.